# IndexOutOfBoundsException error adding long numbers

Tags: java, linked-list, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to wrtie java application that adds up to 5 long numbers using LinkedLists. At the end of the run I get this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   0, Size: 0 
>        at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)    at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:525)     at
>   Assignment1.LongNumbers.remove(LongNumbers.java:33)    at
>   Assignment1.LongNumbers.main(LongNumbers.java:92)

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
/**
*
* @author .....
*/

public class LongNumbers 
{ 
private List<Integer> [] theLists; 
public LongNumbers() { 
    this.theLists = new LinkedList[6]; 
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) 
    this.theLists[i]= new LinkedList<>(); 
} 

public void add(int location, int digit) { 
    //add digit at head of LinkedList given by location 
    theLists[location].add(digit);
} 

public int remove(int location) { 
    //remove a digit from LinkedList given by location
    return theLists[location].remove(location);  //LongNumbers.java:33
} 

public boolean isEmpty(int location) { 
    //check for an empty LinkedList given by location
    return theLists[location].isEmpty();
} 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

     //Local Variables
    int digit;
    int carry = 0;
    int numberAt = 0;
    int largestNumLength = 0;
    char[] digits;
    String number;
    boolean userWantstoQuit = false;
    LongNumbers Lists = new LongNumbers();

    System.out.println("The program will enter up to 5 numbers and add them up.");
    System.out.println();

    while(!userWantstoQuit && numberAt != 5){
        System.out.print("Enter a number, enter -1 to quit entry phase: ");
        number = stdIn.nextLine();

        if((number.compareTo("-1")) == 0)
            userWantstoQuit = true;
        else{
            digits = new char[number.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++)
                digits[i] = number.charAt(i);
            for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++){
                int tempValue = digits[i] - 48;
                try{
                    Lists.add(numberAt, tempValue);
                }
                    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                        System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.");
                        break;
                    }
                if(i == (number.length() - 1))
                    numberAt++;
                if(number.length() > largestNumLength)
                    largestNumLength = number.length();
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<largestNumLength;j++){
        int tempDigit = 0;
        int index = 0;

        while(index < numberAt){
            if(Lists.theLists[index].get(0) != null){
                tempDigit += Lists.theLists[index].get(0);
                Lists.remove(0);  //LongNumbers.java:99                        
            }
        index++;
        }

        digit = carry + tempDigit;

        if(j < numberAt){
            carry = digit/10;
            digit = digit%10;
        }
    Lists.add(5, digit);
    }

    System.out.print("The sum of the numbers is: ");

    for(int i=0;i<Lists.theLists[5].size();i++){
        System.out.print(Lists.theLists[5].get(i));
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

}//end main 
}//end class
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could indicate in your code what's the line "LongNumbers.java:33"

Comment: Sorry about that. Edit has been made

Comment: Your stack trace is telling you quite clearly that, in your `remove()` method, you're asking for the element at index 0 of a list that has a size of zero - i.e. a list that is empty. look at how you're initializing your lists.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I don't think you can have an array of `List<E>` objects...

You should also make sure your list is initialized and has an item at the given `location`.

So your method might look something like this:

```
public int remove(int location)
{ 
     if(theLists != null)
          if(theLists.size() > location)
               return theLists.remove(location);
     return 0;
}
```

If you need 2 dimensions of lists, you could try using `List<List<E>>`

Treat all `E` as `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code here:

```
while(index < numberAt){
            if(Lists.theLists[index].get(0) != null){
                tempDigit += Lists.theLists[index].get(0);
                Lists.remove(0);  //LongNumbers.java:99                        
            }
        index++;
        }
```

You are checking whether the first element of the `index`'th list is not null. If that is true, you are adding it and call the `remove` method. However, what if you already processed the first list and `index`'th value is 1? In that case `theLists[1].get(0) != null` is true, but `Lists.remove(0)` passes 0 as `location`. Take a look at this code:

```
public int remove(int location) { 
    //remove a digit from LinkedList given by location
    return theLists[location].remove(location);  //LongNumbers.java:33
}
```

In the scenario I have described, `location` is 0. But your 0'th list is already empty...

EDIT: Rewrite the `remove` method, like this:

```
public int remove(int location, int index) { 
    //remove a digit from LinkedList given by location
    return theLists[index].remove(location);  //LongNumbers.java:33
}
```

And whenever you call this method, pass the `index` of the list to work with. Example:

```
while(index < numberAt){
            if(Lists.theLists[index].get(0) != null){
                tempDigit += Lists.theLists[index].get(0);
                Lists.remove(0, index);  //LongNumbers.java:99                        
            }
        index++;
        }
```

Finally: In the future, please, structure your code, it was a real pain to read it in this, unstructured state, read about how to code.